# How to calculate user preference?

Tags: r

Based on the data evaluated by users, it tries to find similar users.

How can I find similar users when I have the data below using R?

User2 is more like user1.

How to calculate this?

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
$ user : chr  "user1" "user1" "user1" "user2" ...
$ movie: chr  "movie1" "movie2" "movie3" "movie1" ...
$ score: num  5 4 3 4 4 3 3 4 5
```

[image]

Comment: This is more suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ but I guess KNN works here.

Comment: I think you are looking at clustering techniques to perform may be using content or collaborative filtering, it's beyond the scope here I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the concept of distance between individuals (Took from data mining techniques as first step for ML):

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(user=paste0('user',1:3),
                 movie1=c(5,4,3),
                 movie2=c(4,4,4),
                 movie3=c(3,3,5))
#Format
df2 <- df
rownames(df2) <- df2$user
df2$user <- NULL
#Compute distance
dist(df2)
```

Output:

```
dist(df2)
         user1    user2
user2 1.000000         
user3 2.828427 2.236068
```

Based on previous results, `user1` and `user2` has less distance between them (they are closer), so they can be more similar. I will leave this as an option for you as other data mining methods can be more suitable to understand what you want to reach.